# Deep parameters in binds

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

I wrote the following code without thinking much about what I was doing and I'm really surprised that it actually works as I intended.

Could someone explain why and how bind manages to work with deep parameters?

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
using namespace placeholders;

int main()
{
    vector<string> s = { "abc", "aaaaaaa", "c" };

    for_each(s.begin(),s.end(),
             bind(printf,"string length is %d\n",bind(&string::length,_1)));
}
```

Comment: Apparently `for_each` deep-iterates the vector.

Comment: What is *deep parameters*?

Comment: @Nawaz Parameters that are not parameters of the outside bind, but one of the inside binds. As is shown in the example.

Comment: It is important that this feature is also in `boost::bind`, which was used as the basis of `std::bind` and has probably been generally useful, although a little obscure. Especially confusing is, that there is no `boost::protect` equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard defines the unary type trait `is_bind_expression<T>` which is true if `T` is a call wrapper type returned from `std::bind()`, or if the trait has been specialized for user-defined types.

When the call wrapper is invoked, if any of its bound arguments is a bind expression (as determined by `is_bind_expression`) then that nested bind expression is invoked with all the same arguments as the outer expression was invoked with. The nested bind expression can select out any arguments for which it has a placeholder (`_1` in your example).  This is done recursively, so that invoking the inner bind expression will also check if any of its bound arguments is a bind expression, and invoke them with the same set of arguments and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know exactly how `bind` does this, but I don't see it as a mystery, if you get the distinction.

The type of `bind` could vary based on its input types.  So a `bind` that has a `_1` as an input type can note the fact that it consumes `_1` in its return type (and really, that makes lots of sense).  `bind` could also extract this fact (that there is an unbound `_1` in a parameter) from its parameters.

To quote some `std::bind` documentation:

> If std::is_bind_expression::value == true (i.e. another sbind
>   subexpression was used as an argument in the initial call to bind),
>   then that bind-subexpressin is invoked immediately and its result is
>   passed to the invocable object. If the bind subexpression has any
>   placeholder arguments, they are picked from u1, u2, ....

Comment: The standard does say how it does it, see [func.bind.isbind]/1 and [func.bind.bind]/10. It uses `is_bind_expression` to detect if a bound argument is a bind expression and if so then it is recursively invoked.  It's nothing to do with having `_1` as an input type, it also works for nested bind expressions without placeholders.

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks!  Removed information that I thought I knew I should not know, but it turns out I should know.

Comment: heh :)  you only really need to know it if you want to specialize `is_bind_expression` to make your own types usable with `bind`, so it's specified, but still not usually necessary to know